# Read Xls file having Date Format Column

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb

I do have a xls file with a column Call_Date of DateTime Format.

I am trying to read this file and put it in datatable with connection string property HDR = No ie. i wanna no header row for datatable that reads it.

The first row that i am getting in datatable is the names of columns in xls except call_date having empty string in first row.

I can understand OLEDB might try to read it as datetime format and put it as empty string  with type = "**System.DBNull**" if can't parse it as datetime.

But i need to be have this call_date column name in datatable first row like others.

I can't change the format in xls. can i do it while reading in c# or something else.

My code so far

```
        mCon.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO\";");
        strSelectQuery = "SELECT TOP 20 * FROM [Sheet1$]";
        if (mCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mCon.Open();
        }
        DataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectQuery, mCon);
        DataAdapter.Fill(mDTable);
        mCon.Close();
```

Comment: Any Suggestions.. i m getting stuck here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself after spending hours on searching this topic on internet.

I just modified my connection string to allow OLEDB to read excel file with multiple datatype entry in one column by adding IMEX =1 in extended properties.

My connection string now looks as

```
mCon.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX = 1\";");
```